# SMTP server response: 550 apache php mail server

Tags: php, apache, email

I get this error message

> Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 550-Please
>   turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client, or login to the
>   550-IMAP/POP3 server before sending your message. (sgs5.aws.lan)
>   550-[212.199.198.158]:7165 is not permitted to relay through this
>   server 550 without authentication. in C:\Program
>   Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\PPC-Advert-System\Results\DebuggerFinalResultDB.php
>   on line 32.

The code works on my pc, but when I put it onto another pc it doesnt.. I dont know where is the problem in the configuration.. Here is what I set php.ini to do:

```
   ini_set("SMTP","mail.me.com" );
ini_set("smtp_port","25" );
ini_set("auth_username","username" );
ini_set("auth_password","pass" );
```

Then I user this function:

```
    private function send_an_email($to,$file="",$message="") {
    $subject = 'PCC-Advert-System';
    $message =  $message."<br/><br/><br/>Time Finished Scaning:<br/><br/><br/> ".date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A')."\r\n Ratio: \r\n".$this->ratio." \r\nFile Path:<br/> <a href='http://212.199.198.158/PPC-Advert-System/FileStorage/$file'>http://212.199.198.158/PPC-Advert-System/FileStorage/$file</a><br/><br/><br/><a href='".$this->debug_file."'>$this->debug_file </a> ";//.$this->file;
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers.= 'From: scriptspc@bso.com' . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: scriptspc@bso.com' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo "<br/><br/><h1>Email has been sent</h1>";
}
```

Comment: If you want to use a custom SMTP you should use something like `PHPMailer`, it's hard to send an email using `mail()` and SMTP.

Comment: The solution works.. on my pc..but on a different pc it doesnt. I want to pinpoint the problem.. I am not interested in using another code

Comment: Alright..the phpmailer..seems to work..thanks

Comment: Glad you made that decision, simple `mail()` function is a pain and a time eater.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a custom SMTP you should use something like [PHPMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/), it's hard to send an email using `mail()` and `SMTP`.

Then you can define what SMTP should be used.